# Interceptor for methods async?

Tags: c#, interceptor

Can I intercept a running method if some condition occurs?

This is what I want to do:

```
await Task.Run(() => { Interceptor(); });
await Task.Run(() => { A(); });

private void Interceptor()
{
      //if some condition here, PAUSE whatever is running in A(), do "something" and then re-run A()- wheter where it stopped or re-run the whole method A again
}

private void A()
{
    B();
    C();
    .....
    D();
}
```

This is what I am doing:

```
await Task.Run(() => { A(); });

private void Interceptor()
{
      if(condition)
      {
           Foo();
      }
}

private void A()
{
    Interceptor();
    B();
    Interceptor();
    C();
    Interceptor();
    .....
    Interceptor();
    D();
    Interceptor();
}
```

Is there a way to do this? The point is that I have a very dynammic `A()` method and the `Interceptor` condition may occur at any point... (including inside the methods B,C,D and so on...)

Comment: The code you show (`await Task.Run` etc.) will run `Interceptor` on a thread pool thread, and then, after that's complete, run `A` on a thread pool thread. You probably want to look up `CancelationTokens`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for you to check the interceptor between every method call is either:

- The methods must not be run if a cancellation signal is raised
- the methods are synchronous and takes time to execute

In most other scenarios it's just a waste of time and makes the code harder to read.

If the methods in `A()` is async, stop reading here and use a cancellation token instead.

If the methods are synchronous and takes time, or must be aborted, it's better to just create a pipeline where each method is executed in turn:

```
public static class ExecutionExtensions
{
    public static void Execute(this IEnumerable<Action> pipeline, Func<bool> cancellationFunction)
    {
        foreach (var action in pipeline)
        {
            action();
            if (cancellationFunction())
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just define the flow:

```
// Requires that the methods are in the same class
var a = new List<Action> { B, C, D, E };
```

And execute it:

```
// interceptor must return true when the execution should be halted.
a.Execute(Interceptor);
```

Complete code:

```
public class AClass
{
    private void B()
    {

    }

    private void C()
    {

    }

    private void D()
    {

    }

    private bool Interceptor()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void A()
    {
        var pipeline = new List<Action> { B, C, D };
        pipeline.Execute(Interceptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the methods are synchronous and takes time (some of them have eternal loops with some break condition - which might not occur if the Interceptor condition says "hello"). What I have done is "tryUntilSuccessOrTimeout" and then recheck the Interceptor again... but it's pretty ugly I guess... is there any other solution? I was thinking in two threads in parallell (interceptor and the "pipeline") and when Interceptor occurs, pause the pipeline thread, finish interceptor and then resume the pipeline.

Comment: Just don't return from the interceptor callback until the interceptor is done.